# Linkedin API Python

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I'm trying to log-in to Linkedin. I created the App and extract the client_key and client_secret. Also I added http://localhost:8080/ as Redirect URLs.
I have this error:

> linkedin.exceptions.LinkedInError: 410 Client Error: Gone for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~: This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs

```
# pip install python-linkedin
from linkedin import linkedin
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''

consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

request_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken'
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "POST")
if resp['status'] != '200':
    raise Exception('Invalid response %s.' % resp['status'])
content_utf8 = str(content, 'utf-8')
request_token = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(content_utf8))
authorize_url = request_token['xoauth_request_auth_url']

print('Go to the following link in your browser:', "\n")
print(authorize_url + '?oauth_token=' + request_token['oauth_token'])

accepted = 'n'
while accepted.lower() == 'n':
    accepted = input('Have you authorized me? (y/n)')
oauth_verifier = input('What is the PIN?')

access_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken'
token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
token.set_verifier(oauth_verifier)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)
resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, 'POST')
content8 = str(content, 'utf-8')
access_token = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(content8))
USER_TOKEN = access_token['oauth_token']
USER_SECRET = access_token['oauth_token_secret']
RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8080'

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(
    consumer_key,
    consumer_secret,
    USER_TOKEN,
    USER_SECRET,
    RETURN_URL,
    linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values()
)
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
application.get_profile()
```

Comment: whats your question

Comment: I cant get_profile() info

Comment: right and the API response is 410 which means that this specific resource is no longer available. So basically the address is not there, don't blame yourself on your code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410

Answer (score 1):

The v1 APIs are no longer supported.
Applications requesting Version 1.0 APIs may experience issues as they are removing services. Hence, it is highly recommended to change it from `v1` to `v2`.
Link : https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates
Try updating your code with the new set of APIs (currently v2), and it will work perfectly as you're expecting.
Link : https://pypi.org/project/python-linkedin-v2/

Hope it helps!

Comment: I did that but now i have this error: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

Comment: Change `request_token_url` to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken`, and then let me know what reponse you obtain.

Comment: Refer this link for further details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context#step-2-generate-an-access-token

Comment: Exception: Invalid response 400

Comment: You'll have to make a few changes in your code as mentioned here : https://pypi.org/project/python-linkedin-v2/

Comment: I did all the url said, can you help me?

Comment: Yes sure..What's the issue you are facing next?